# Flask-SocketIO socket fails to connect and continuously re-attempts

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have an app that's outputting a JSON through a socket which was working fine in the past, however recently the socket doesn't seem to be establishing and it continuously POST & GET's with the lines:

```
<user_ip>,<client_ip> - - [17/Jul/2018 12:48:17]"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling......HTTP/1.1" 200 221 0.000000
<user_ip>,<client_ip> - - [17/Jul/2018 12:48:17]"POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling......HTTP/1.1" 200 243 0.517600
```

Additionally, when the WebSocket first tries, I can see from Chromes console the message:

> WebSocket connection to ..... failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed.

I've also had a look through what I think is a [similar issue](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/65)  based on socketIO-client but wasn't able to resolve my problem.

Can anyone help with overcoming this connection issue?

Included a full log on running the app below:

```
Server initialized for eventlet.
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 129-744-633
(7616) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:6328
(7616) accepted (<client_ip>, 50548)
<user_ip>,<client_ip> - - [17/Jul/2018 13:18:23] "GET /<app_url> HTTP/1.1" 200 1664 0.015000
3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
<user_ip>,<client_ip> - - [17/Jul/2018 13:18:23] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1531829903367-0 HTTP/1.1" 200 381 0.000000
(7616) accepted (<client_ip>, 50560)
3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/testnamespace
3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0/testnamespace
<user_ip>,<client_ip> - - [17/Jul/2018 13:18:23] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1531829903377-1&sid=3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8 HTTP/1.1" 200 221 0.000000
<user_ip>,<client_ip> - - [17/Jul/2018 13:18:23] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1531829903379-2&sid=3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8 HTTP/1.1" 200 226 0.000000
(7616) accepted (<client_ip>, 50562)
3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8: Received packet MESSAGE data 2/testnamespace,["event_1",{"data":"Web app connection successful."}]
3602c46fa50247eb9d397fda82f3eae8: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2/testnamespace,["client_event",{"json":[{"Date&Time":"........}]
```

Comment: Is Chrome connection on port 6328 of your service, or is there a reverse proxy in between the client and the server? The error comes from the client, it is not related to your application. It could mean that your client's network does not allow connections on that port, or that websocket isn't allowed at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm accessing the app on that port but my Chrome has a proxy server enabled for my LAN. I've tried changing ports already, and this issue arose a few days ago, but has disappeared occasionally (if that provides any colour).